# Replicate IIS Settings for Load Balanced Websites

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, load-balancing

I have a website running on two Windows Server 2008 boxes using built in Network Load Balancing. I replicate the website files via DFS replication.

What is the easiest way to replicate the IIS settings across both servers so that I only have to update one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to look into IIS7 Shared Configuration.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/264/shared-configuration/